# jquery animate does not work correctly in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a couple of components in a webpage I plan to use as a model. [Here is the code in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lKOVC5E3mYOSRzP3qKJf?p=preview). When the viewport is small, and the boxes are placed under each other (mobile phone view), everything works well. When you click on one of the categories, more information is shown, as expected.

On a large view however, this does not work in Chrome as expected. For some reason, the parent element jumps way up. I don't know what is causing this behavior, but surprisingly enough it works perfectly running on FF and Internet Explorer (yes for real!).

I have searched stackoverflow and mostly ran into animation problems from a couple of years ago. They don't come up with a solution for me. I have also tried to use the addClass and removeClass functions with css animations instead of using animate() function, but strangly enough I get the same result!

The javascript is not the best (its below the html code), i am aware of that, but here is the piece I think that is causing all of this:

```
var menu = $(".menu-text"),
            aanbod = $(".aanbod-title"),
            ....

aanbod.click(function(){



            var parent = $(this).parents(".aanbod-widget"),
                curheight = parent.css("height"),
                vpWidth = $(window).width(),
                targetHeight = $(this).css("height");


            console.log("this parent", $(this).parent("aanbod-title-bg"));

            /*  Here it starts I think. If vpWidth is below 740, all is fine, probably because affects a different element in the DOM
 */
            if(vpWidth <= 740) {
                if(curheight === '120px') {
                    parent.animate({height:'515px'}, 250);
                }
                else{
                    parent.animate({height:'120px'}, 250);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(targetHeight === '515px') {
                    $(this).animate({height: '120px', 'line-height': '120px'}, 250);
                    $(this).parent(".aanbod-title-bg").animate({height: '120px'}, 250);

                }
                else{
                    $(this).animate({height: '515px', 'line-height': '511px'}, 250);
                    $(this).parent(".aanbod-title-bg").animate({height: '515px'}, 250);
                }
            }
        });
```

what can I do to fix this? I have no idea what is going wrong. Thanks a lot!

Edit: I forgot to mention this fact: In a large viewport, click a category and it jump. Then slightly resize the viewport. All is in the correct place then. Very weird! Since I noticed this, I have also tried to trigger a fake window resize, but that doesn't work either. I am actually glad it doesn't work, because it feels like a dirty hack.

Comment: can you put your HTML, CSS and jQuery in a fiddle and share the link?

Comment: i dont have a fiddle account yet, but i can make one tomorrow. Is the plunker link not working?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it :)